# Core Data NSManagedObject: Max Number of Attributes?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

I'd like to know if there is a guideline for the maximum number of attributes any one NSManagedObject subclass should have. I've read Apple's docs carefully, but find no mention of a limit where performance starts to erode.

I DO see a compiler flag option in Xcode that provides a warning when an NSManagedObject has more than 100 attributes, but I can't find any documentation on it. Does anyone here have experience with Core Data MOs that have a large number of attributes?

I'm focused on ***performance***, not memory usage. In my app, there will only ever be about 10-20 instances of this MO that has a large number of attributes and I'm developing on OS X rather than iOS, so memory usage isn't a factor. But if there is a point where performance (especially when faulting) starts to die, I'd like to know now so I can change the structure of my data model accordingly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Each attribute gets mapped to a table column](http://blog.chrismiles.info/2011/07/core-data-debugging-with-sqlite.html), if you're using SQLite backing stores.  SQLite has a hard limit on the number of columns you can use (2000 by default, though it's compile-time configurable so Apple's implementation could differ), and [they recommend not using more than one hundred](http://sqlite.org/limits.html).  That could well be why the Xcode warning sets its threshold at 100.

That same linked page on limits also notes that there are some O(N^2) algorithms where N is the number of columns, so, sounds like you should generally avoid high numbers.

For other file formats, I don't know of any limits or recommendations.  But I'd expect similar things - i.e. there's probably some algorithm in there that's O(N^2) or worse, so you want to avoid becoming an uncommon edge case.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using XML as the backing store, so I don't need to worry about the SQLite limit. It does sound like this is the reason that compiler flag exists though, which is definitely helpful. I don't anticipate ever needing more than ~150 attributes, so I think I'll be okay. I appreciate the links!

Answer (score 3):

Not that I have run across even on iOS.  The biggest limiting factor of performance is the cache size in the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` which on Mac OSX is pretty big.

If your attributes are strings, numbers, dates, etc. (i.e. not binary data) then you can probably have a huge number of attributes before you start to see a performance hit.  If you are working with binary data then I would caution you against blowing the cache and consider storing binary data outside of SQLite.  More recent versions of the OS can even do this automatically for you.

However, I would question why you would want to do this.  Surely there are attributes that are going to be less vital than others and can be abstracted away into child entities on the other side of a one-to-one relationship?